# How to recognize different NSTabView

Tags: cocoa

I notice there is no tag parameter for NSTabView.(For NSButton I can use tag to access different button)
But if there are more than 1 NSTabView on a window, how to recognize different NSTabView?
Of course, I know I can use

> IBOutlet NSTabView *tabview1;
>
> } @property (retain,nonatomic)
>   IBOutlet NSTabView *tabview1;

Is there any other way to access different NSTabView just like using tag to access NSButton?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every NSView has a `tag` property of type `NSInteger` (which is just a typedef for `int`). Just assign a different value to the two or more table views and use it to later distinguish the views.

Comment: Thanks. But I can not find where to set it in Interface Builder.

Comment: According to Apple's documentation, you need to subclass NSView (or NSTabView in your case) and implement an own `-setTag:` method. The default implementation of `-tag` returns `-1`. So there won't be any chance to set the value in Interface builder, because it cannot know your custom subclasses.

Comment: By the way, this is different in iOS for `UIView`. In contrast to `NSView`, the `UIView` implentation does define a setter method for `tag`.